# Python 2.7 replace defined file location with $user

Tags: python, unix, python-2.7

I would like to replace

```
XML_FPATH = '/home/MyUserName/git/somefile.xml'
```

with

```
XML_FPATH = '/home/$user/git/somefile.xml'
```

So any user with that git folder can run my script.

Comment: Please specify your problem statement

Comment: And what if user has `git` in different folder - for example `~/my_priv_gits` ?

Comment: This is assuming folder structure is the same. Which it is

Comment: Did you try `~` (tylda) ?

Comment: Can you be more specific?

Comment: Sorry `~` works in Bash. Try `os.environ['HOME'] + '/git/somefile.xml'`

Answer (score 0):

i figured it out.

```
import getpass

XML_FPATH = '/home/' + getpass.getuser() +
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
XML_FPATH =  os.environ['HOME'] + '/git/somefile.xml'
```

or

```
XML_FPATH =  os.path.expanduser('~') + '/git/somefile.xml'
```

If you need home folder of `other_user` then try

```
XML_FPATH =  os.path.expanduser('~other_user') + '/git/somefile.xml'
```

For `root` you get correct folder `/root/git/somefile.xml`